# iphone - Message sent to deallocated instance in a block

Tags: iphone, autorelease

I have this property called mySegmented, declared like this

```
.h
@property (retain)  UISegmentedControl *mySegmented;


.m
@synthesize mySegmented = _mySegmented;
```

then, it was created like this:

```
self.mySegmented = [self createSegmented];
// createSegmented creates an autoreleased segmented control
```

My app has 3 different segmented controls. Just one appears at a given time. 
At some point of my app, I have to hide one particular segmented control, so, what I do is to build an array of all segmented controls and iterate... this is inside a block.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8

             animations:^{

                 NSArray *list = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  self.mySegmented1,
                                  self.mySegmented2,
                                  self.mySegmented3,
                                  nil];

                 for (UISegmentedControl *oneSeg in list) {
                     [oneSeg setAlpha:0.0f];
                 }

             }];
```

what happens is: after some time, the app crashes while trying to build this array. I suppose one of the segmented controls is deallocated somehow. No deallocation that I can see in code.

My question is: this array being created is autoreleased. What happens when the block finishes the animation? is a release sent to each member of the array?

If I retain the segmented control after creating it, Xcode complains it will leak.

any clues?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please retain like you tried, but make sure to release them in the `dealloc` method, Xcode should not complain that way.

Your array is also autoreleased inside the block but that's fine, the array doesn't own the references inside of it, the real problem is the segmented controls not being retained by your view controller.

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: in my dealloc I have [_mySegmented1 release];  [_mySegmented2 release];  [_mySegmented3 release];  How am I suppose to release it? [self.mySegmented1 release]; ??????????????

Comment: Hi, yes that looks good provided you `@synthesize mySegmented1 = _mySegmented1;` in your implementation. This will release those objects when the View controller is released, now when you get your object you want to do `self.mySegmented1 = [[self createSegmented] retain];`

Comment: Doing `self.mySegmented1 = [[self createSegmented] retain]` is going to retain the object too many times since you are both manually retaining it and assigning it to a retained property. This will almost certainly cause a memory leak.

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with the code that the OP posted. His code indicates the `segmented1` etc. are retaining properties and he is correctly retaining them already. He should not retain them again.